# Javascript time, pluralities 1 min vs 1 mins. Timer for time notification received

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, date

```
self.calcMessageAge = function calcMessageAge(fireDate){
    var date = Date.parse(fireDate);
    var now = new Date();
    now = Date.now();

    // in seconds
    var diff = Math.abs(date - now)/1000;
    if(diff < 60) {
        return "1 min";
    }else if(diff < (60*60) ) {
        // minutes
        return Math.floor(diff/60) + " mins";

    } else if(diff < (60*60*24)) {
        // hours
        var hrs = Math.floor(diff/60/60) + " hours";
        if(hrs !== "1 hours") {
            return Math.floor(diff/60/60) + " hours";
        } else {
            return Math.floor(diff/60/60) + " hour";
        }
    } else if(diff < (60*60*24*7)) {
        // days
        var _day = Math.floor(diff/24/60/60) + " days";
        if(_day !== "1 days") {
            return Math.floor(diff/24/60/60) + " days";
        } else {
            return Math.floor(diff/24/60/60) + " day";
        }

    } else if(diff < (60*60*24*7*4)) {
        // weeks
        var _weeks = Math.floor(diff/7/24/60/60) + " weeks";
        if(_weeks !== "1 weeks") {
            return Math.floor(diff/7/24/60/60) + " weeks";
        } else {
            return Math.floor(diff/7/24/60/60) + " week";
        }
    } else {
        var _months = Math.floor(diff/4/7/24/60/60) + " months";
        if(_months !== "1 months") {
            return Math.floor(diff/4/7/24/60/60) + " months";
        } else {
            return Math.floor(diff/4/7/24/60/60) + " month";
        }
    }
};
```

The Above method should return a string based on the time (fireDate) that a notification reached the UI. 
String such as "1 min ago" or "1 day ago" then "2 mins ago" or "2 days ago"

I am receiving "1 min ago" correctly but at 60 seconds I get "1 mins" returned, This also happens with day(s).

Im thinking it has to do with the fact Im checking against 60seconds when it should be 59? Im really kinda stumped. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: use `<=` instead of `<` for the comparison

Comment: I... what? You do the math and concatenate a string, then based on the result you do the math again and concatenate the same string or a different one? Wouldn't it make more sense to do the math once, check the result, *then* concatenate the appropriate string? If nothing else it'd make it much, much easier to read.

Comment: @DaveNewton you are absolutely correct. At this point I have been tasked with a quick and dirty fix for this. I inherited the code, this is the first time I've seen how this was done. Believe me, I will be doing it right in a week or two. when I have a little time.

Comment: The title seems to be a bunch of words pushed together. Can you [edit] that to be more descriptive of your issue, as a sentence?

Comment: `diff < 60` should just be `diff <= 60`. If you want to get technical, it's technically `1 min ago` up until 2 mins, so you can do `diff < 120` for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```js
const getDiffrence = fireDate => {
  const date = new Date(fireDate).getTime();
  let now = new Date().getTime();
  const diff = Math.abs(date - now) / 1000
  const min = Math.floor(diff/60) % 60 || ''
  const h = Math.floor(diff/60/60) % 60 || ''
  const day = Math.floor(diff/60/60/24) % 24 || ''
  const week = Math.floor(diff/60/60/24/7)|| ''
  const month = Math.floor(diff/4/7/24/60/60) || ''
  return `${month ? month + 'months' : ''} ${week ? week + 'weeks' : ''} ${day ? day + 'days' : ''} ${day ? day + 'days' : ''} ${h ? h + 'hours' : ''} ${min ? min + 'mins' : ''} `.replace(/\b(1\D+?)s/g, '$1').trim()
}

console.log(getDiffrence('2017/02/27 18:22'))
console.log(getDiffrence(new Date().getTime() - 60 * 1000 - 5000))
```

The main part of this code is `.replace(/\b(1\D+?)s/g, '$1')`
this will replace all `1 anythings` with `1 anything` or evnen crazer at this after it `.replace(/(0\D+?)s\s*/g, '')` and you just have to create string like `'1days 0hours 0minutes'`

```js
console.log('11mounths 1days 0hours 20minutes'.replace(/\b0\D+?s\s*/g, '').replace(/\b(1\D+?)s/g, '$1'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var calcMessageAge = function(fireDate) {
  var date = Date.parse(fireDate);
  var now = Date.now();
  // in seconds
  var diff = Math.abs(date - now) / 1000;
  var minute = 60;
  var hour = 60 * minute;
  var day = 24 * hour;
  var week = 7 * day;
  var month = 4 * week; // month is usually longer than 4 weeks but I let the same as in original code
  var num;
  var label;

  if (diff > month) {
    num = Math.floor(diff / month);
    label = num + ' month' + (num > 1 ? 's': '');
  } else if (diff > week) {
    num = Math.floor(diff / week);
    label = num + ' week' + (num > 1 ? 's': '');
  } else if (diff > day) {
    num = Math.floor(diff / day);
    label = num + ' day' + (num > 1 ? 's': '');
  } else if (diff > hour) {
    num = Math.floor(diff / hour);
    label = num + ' hour' + (num > 1 ? 's': '');
  } else if (diff > minute) {
    num = Math.floor(diff / minute);
    label = num + ' min' + (num > 1 ? 's': '');
  } else {
    label = '1 min';
  }

  return label;
};

console.log(calcMessageAge('02-02-2017'));
console.log(calcMessageAge('01-01-2017 20:00'));
console.log(calcMessageAge(new Date(new Date().getTime() - 60 * 1000)));
console.log(calcMessageAge(new Date(new Date().getTime() - 59 * 1000)));
console.log(calcMessageAge(new Date(new Date().getTime() - 60 * 60 * 4 * 1000)));
```